# Wire Wrap Joint in High Humidity

Tags: soldering, wire, reliability, humidity

How does a wire wrap joint compare to a soldered joint in high humidity conditions?

Corrosion? Electrolysis? Joint resistance creeping up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Properly made wire wrap joints are probably the most durable of electrical connections.  I worked in the defense industry for many years during which most of the connections between circuit boards were done by backplanes containing thousands of wire wrap connections. Each connection is done by wrapping the wire several times around a rectangular pin with very sharp sides. Because of the tightness of the wrap, there is a gas tight connection made every time the wire touches each side of the pin.  A typical wrap could have a dozen or more of these connections. In my experience, I never heard of a single failure due to a bad wirewrap connection even though these systems were exposed to severe environments including submarines.